# Bash script to zip files that begin with the same characters, and name zip files based on file name

Tags: bash, macos

I have exported a lot of images to a folder and would like to group and zip them based on their file name, while also naming the zip-file based on the images file name, eg:

foretagshus1.jpg; foretagshus2.jpg; foretagshus3.jpg -> foretagshus.zip

annathus1.jpg; annathus2.jpg; annathus3.jpg -> annathus.zip

I have the option to put the number as a prefix instead of a suffix if that makes it easier. 
I'm a newbie to bash and scripting in general so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I think you just need to say `zip foretagshus.zip foretagshus*` and then `zip annathus.zip annathus*`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's possible to iterate over the image names, you can run the following logic

- For each image

  - Find ZIP file (strip suffix, strip number, add .zip)
  - If ZIP exists, skip
  - Build ZIP file

With

```
for file in *.jpg ; do
   bb=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/[0-9]*.jpg$//' )
   if [ -f "$bb.zip" ] ; then continue ; fi
   # Create zip file for all files with this prefix, and numeric suffix.
   echo "Building: $bb.zip"
   zip $bb.zip $bb[0-9]*.jpg
done
```